# Algebra of limits. What NBD means?

Tags: limits, terminology

> **9.** If $f(x)\le g(x)$ for every $x$ in the NBD of $a$, then
>   $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\le\lim_{x\to a}g(x).$$

NBD stands for what?

Comment: "NeighBourhooD"?

Comment: What is neant by neighbourhood

Comment: Ok i understood

Comment: Yes, neighborhood, although I have to say, abbreviating that, unless it's used all over the place (in which case it should be obvious what it means), is a bit odd.